# How can I set a shared pointer to a regular pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I'm completely news to shared pointers. I'm trying to initialize one by doing

```
std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen(new Gdiplus::Pen);
```

but it says that it needs a type specifier.... I am also trying to set this shared pointer to 
a regular pointer. Can anyone explain me how this works. Much appreciated

```
#pragma once
class Shape
{
public:
Shape();
Gdiplus::Point start;   
Gdiplus::Point end;

std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen(new Gdiplus::Pen());
virtual  LRESULT Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics * m_GraphicsImage) = 0;


void setPen(Gdiplus::Pen * pen2) {

    pen.get() = pen2; 
}
void setStart(int xPos, int yPos) {
    start.X = xPos;
    start.Y = yPos;
}
void setEnd(int xCor, int yCor) {
    end.X = xCor;
    end.Y = yCor;
}
```

};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen(new Gdiplus::Pen);
```

should be

```
std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen(new Gdiplus::Pen(brush, width));
```

or whatever your constructor looks like

getting a raw pointer from shared_ptr

```
setPen(pen.get());
```

hint: be careful with setting raw pointers which are controlled by smart pointers. are you sure that you don't want to pass a smart pointer (shared or unique)?

you should also create your shared pointer through the std helper function

```
auto pen = std::make_shared<Gdiplus::Pen>(brush, width);
```

Comment: i don't quite understand. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says that there are two arguments - which of course need to get passed to the constructor

Comment: error C2039: 'shared_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: these are the errors that i'm getting, and yes and i'm doing include<memory>. when i just have std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen; i get no errors...

Comment: can you post your whole testcase?

Comment: you can not initialize a member in the class itself. your member should be std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen which gets initialized in the initializer list/constructor

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26980/discussion-between-daniel-and-user1665569)

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. How can i set the shared_ptr to a regular pointer

Answer (score 0):

Use `get` from the shared_ptr to pass it as a raw pointer:

```
setPen(pen.get());
```

But make sure you are not storing it inside setPen. That would lead to nasty bugs later on.

Comment: Nope you can't assign to pen.get()